# Remove part of JSON data set

Tags: angular

I have a JSON data set and I need to remove a certain portion of it based on a value I have in another data set.

This is the data set(this.portfolioOptionsData) that I would like to remove from.

```
[
    {
        "investmentStrategy": "Comprehensive",
        "selectedDefault": null,
        "portfolioDetail": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "portfolioNames": "AFRF Accelerator portfolio",
                "riskRating": {
                    "conservative": false,
                    "aggressive": true,
                    "moderate": false
                },
                "managements": "Active"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "investmentStrategy": "Lifestage",
        "selectedDefault": null,
        "portfolioDetail": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "portfolioNames": "AF High Growth portfolio",
                "riskRating": {
                    "conservative": false,
                    "aggressive": true,
                    "moderate": false
                },
                "managements": "Active"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The value I am checking against is the `investmentStrategy`.

The next data set is where I can check what `investmentStrategy`

```
{
  "defaultOptionId": 1,
  "hasClarity": null,
  "hasSinglePortfolio": null,
  "isComprehensive": false,
  "isLifestage": true,
  "lifestage": {
    "isBalanced": true,
    "isPassive": true,
    "isSpecialist": true
  },
  "portfolioOptionId": null,
  "defaultLabelName": "Lifestage – Passive"
}
```

So in this instance I can see that `"isLifestage": true`, which means that I need to remove the `comprehensive` portion from the first data set.

```
{
  "investmentStrategy": "Comprehensive",
  "selectedDefault": null,
  "portfolioDetail": [
    {
     "id": 9,
     "portfolioNames": "AFRF Accelerator portfolio",
     "riskRating": {
     "conservative": false,
     "aggressive": true,
     "moderate": false
    },
      "managements": "Active"
    }
   ]
}
```

Any ideas how I can go about this?

I have tried the following which does remove data accordingly but I have to check each `investmentStrategy`value manually? Is there an easier way?

if ( this.isLifestage ) {
   this.portfolioOptionsData.splice(0,1);
   console.log("new base "+ JSON.stringify(this.portfolioOptionsData));
}

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have added my attempt but am confused about how to go about this

Comment: If you can add 1 attribute more , i can suggest you something. you create a boolean attribute in you object "displayed: true or false". When you point the "isComprehensive" attribute in the second data set and it's also in first data set , you can change the "displayed" attribute to false. And check this attribute before render item in HTML.

Comment: Do you want to remove `investmentStrategy` from all the elements of the array or just one that matches? you can use `delete` keyword to remove a key from a json object.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an array that you want to remove some items from based on a condition.

A simple Javascript problem requires a simple Javascript solution (with a bit of Typescript for fun).

The first thing I would do is create a function that determines whether or not any given item in the array should be kept. I find it easier to think in positive terms rather than negative terms when creating a predicate.

```js
private shouldKeep(check: { isComprehensive: boolean, isLifestage: boolean },
  item: { investmentStrategy: string }): boolean {
  return (check.isComprehensive && item.investmentStrategy === 'Comprehensive') || 
    (check.isLifestage && item.investmentStrategy === 'Lifestage');
}
```

Now you can call this function using whatever array function you wish. You just have to think about *how* you're going to remove items.

You have 2 clear options:

1. Delete from the original array
2. Create a new array with only the items to keep

You must preserve the original array if anything else is referencing it.

#### 1. Delete from the original array

Use `splice` to remove items from an array

```js
for (let i = this.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (!this.shouldKeep(this.check, this.data[i])) {
    this.data.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

#### 2. Create a new array

Use the `filter` method to copy only the items you want to keep to a new array.

```js
this.data = this.data.filter(x => this.shouldKeep(this.check, x));
```

#### 3. Hybrid

Copy the items into a temp array, clear the original array, and push the filtered items back into the original array.

```js
const filtered = this.data.filter(x => this.shouldKeep(this.check, x));
this.data.splice(0, this.data.length);
this.data.push(...filtered);
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-id6l7q